# I want to download the contents of table after giving search criteria into a file in html format using selenium webdriver with python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I want to download the contents of table after giving search criteria into a file in html format using selenium webdriver with python.

[URL to the content table:](https://www.tis.bizfile.gov.sg//ngbtisinternet/faces/oracle/webcenter/portalapp/pages/productlisting/ishopProductListing.jspx?EntityNo=201228154Z&producttype=ALL&_afrLoop=163347378044200&_afrWindowMode=0&_afrWindowId=1kqsaugkt_6#%40%3F_afrWindowId%3D1kqsaugkt_6%26_afrLoop%3D163347378044200%26EntityNo%3D201228154Z%26producttype%3DALL%26_afrWindowMode%3D0%26_adf.ctrl-state%3D1kqsaugkt_38)

at end of page in Extracts, i gave Transcation Date as Last 1 year and clicked Find button.

this gives a new table. i want to download the contents of table into a file as html format.

this is my code

from datetime import datetime

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import time
import requests
from lxml import html
from time import time


def get_master_data(uen):
    crawler_tracker = None
    start_time = time()

    din = []
    master_data = {
    'uen':'',
    'directors':[]
    }

    p = open("/home/termsheet/Desktop/practo2.html","r")
    str_text = p.read()

    tree = html.fromstring(str_text)

    if not (tree.xpath('//form[@id="f1"]')):
    raise "f1 form not found"

    return

    if (tree.xpath('//form[@id="f1"]')):
    print('//form[@id="f1"]')


    if tree.xpath('//*[@id="pt1:r1:s33:plam1"]/td[2]/span'):
        uen = tree.xpath('//*[@id="pt1:r1:s33:plam1"]/td[2]/span/text()')[0]
        master_data['uen'] = uen
        print( "UEN: "+ uen)

    if tree.xpath('//*[@id="pt1:r1:s33:plam3"]/td[2]/span'):
        Status = tree.xpath('//*[@id="pt1:r1:s33:plam3"]/td[2]/span/text()')[0]
        print( "Status: "+ Status)

    if tree.xpath('//*[@id="pt1:r1:s33:pgl249"]/div[1]/span'):
        Address = tree.xpath('//*[@id="pt1:r1:s33:pgl249"]/div/span/text()')
        final = Address[0]+','+Address[1]+','+Address[2]
        last_line = tree.xpath('//*[@id="pt1:r1:s33:pgl228"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/span/text()')[0]
        print("Address: "+final)
        print(last_line)




get_master_data("201228154Z")



from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import codecs
import xml.dom.minidom
import time

class Acra():

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver.exe")
    base_url = "https://www.tis.bizfile.gov.sg/"
    driver.get(base_url+ "/ngbtisinternet/faces/oracle/webcenter/portalapp/pages/productlisting/ishopProductListing.jspx?EntityNo=201228154Z&producttype=ALL&_afrLoop=163347378044200&_afrWindowMode=0&_afrWindowId=1kqsaugkt_6#%40%3F_afrWindowId%3D1kqsaugkt_6%26_afrLoop%3D163347378044200%26EntityNo%3D201228154Z%26producttype%3DALL%26_afrWindowMode%3D0%26_adf.ctrl-state%3D1kqsaugkt_38")
    s=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("pt1:r1:s33:soc1::content")).select_by_visible_text("Last 1 Year")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("option[title=\"Last 1 Year\"]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("pt1:r1:s33:cb4").click()
    time.sleep(10)




Acra()
```

Comment: What is your question? Don't ask someone to write code for you - describe your issue and ask how to solve it

Comment: Unable to download hidden elements in html page